# When will the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide content be allowed on Adventurer's League?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

If at all—is there a way to know when the player options in SCAG will be available in AL? According to the latest [AL Guide](http://dndadventurersleague.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Guide-3.0.pdf) I found, only PHB and few other minor resources are allowed.

Comment: I think you've already answered your own question with that link.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know much about AL, so, my question is aiming for something like a timetable/calendar (if it exists) of when released content is "rolled into" official play (which I think is how it worked with Pathfinder Society, not sure how it works here).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* is, in fact, already allowed material for Adventurer's League. It does not appear in the current AL Guide because it was published *after* the current AL Guide. However, AL put out an [announcement](http://dndadventurersleague.org/the-sword-coast-adventurers-guide-and-you/) about it. You should read the link, but:

> Everyone, regardless of story origin (season) has the possibility of using the options presented in the Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide. Add the allowed portions of the Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide to the list of allowed rules for every story origin (see below).

Also, note that:

> The D&D Adventurers League Player’s Guide will be updated with this information next season.

In other words, they're not going to bother with a revised Player's Guide this season, but from next season onwards the Player's Guide will include SCAG as an allowed option.

Comment: To clarify, SCAG won't be listed in the guide as legal material until next season, but is allowed in the current season thanks to the referenced announcement?

Comment: @ObliviousSage Yep. Its omission in the guide is solely due to the guide not being updated to match the current state of AL.