# What resources do I need to have all races/classes available to me for Adventurer's League?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, dnd-adventurers-league

I'm still a relative noob to DnD and am playing 5e. We will be starting the Curse of Strahd on March 16 and I would like to be planning out my character. I'm having some trouble figuring out where to get information on races/classes outside of the player's handbook. Where else should I look to find listings/descriptions/rules/etc. relating to the races/classes that I can play legally in Adventurer's league?

The sort of case that brings on this question would be this.

["Choose a race. This season, you can use any race from the rules listed above, except for aarakocra."](http://dnd.wizards.com/playevents/players). I've never heard of this particular race. I found it in the monster manual, but I don't understand how that allows you to build a PC. That's why I'm curious about where all I can source my build from.

Comment: I had the tag in there, because I'm interested in the "by the book" answer. From what I've gathered so far, Adventurer's League seems much more restrictive and less loosey-goosey than general play. Having greater emphasis on rules, so I was trying to tag for the most precise answer.

Comment: Ah, OK. Figuring out what obeys AL regulations isn't really a rules-as-written exercise, because no matter what someone analyses the regulations as *saying*, AL officials are the final authority and no amount of “the RAW says” can alter that. That means the [dnd-adventurers-league] tag is plenty, since the question is just asking for clarification on what the regulations are.

Answer (score 7):

All the information you need, including what resources you will need, in addition to what classes and races are legal for play, can be found on the [Organized Play section of the Wizards of the Coast website](http://dnd.wizards.com/playevents/players).

Comment: Thanks, I see. I guess some of my questions won't be answered until the Adventurer's League play guide for the upcoming season is available.

Answer (score 5):

The free [Elemental Evil Player's Companion](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/elementalevil_playerscompanion) details some additional races that aren't in the Players Handbook.

- Aarakocra
- Deep Gnome
- Genasi (Air/Earth/Fire/Water)
- Goliath

The Adventurers League Players Guide for the Elemental Evil season allowed you to create characters of any of these races *except Aarakocra*.
ALPG for Rage of Demons season did not allow you to *create* characters of these races, though you could carry over previously created characters.

The hardback [Sword Coast Adventurers Guide](http://dndadventurersleague.org/the-sword-coast-adventurers-guide-and-you/) also has character options that are allowed for AL, with some exceptions:

> The following rules options are either not allowed, or are restricted in some way:
>
> - The “Winged” option granting a fly speed for tieflings is not legal for D&D Adventurers League play. [...]
> - Races or other options that are mentioned but whose rules are found in another source (i.e. aasimar or genasi) do not become legal without other campaign documentation unless that source is also legal for your character’s story origin.
> - The Inheritor background requires additional guidance. [...]
> - Only dwarves can become battleragers. [...]
> - Only elves and half-elves can become bladesingers. [...]
> - All human languages listed on page 112 are legal for use in Dungeons & Dragons Adventurers League play.

Unless the AL Players Guide for Curse of Strahd says differently, new characters will be restricted to options listed in PHB and SCAG.

The latest AL Players Guide can be found on the [Adventurers League Resources page](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/events/adventurers-league-resources).
*(as of writing this, the latest is Rage of Demons)*

Comment: [SCAG is an allowed resource for all players in all seasons](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/72454/15469), so it really ought to be included.

Answer (score 3):

> The sort of case that brings on this question would be this.
>
> "Choose a race. This season, you can use any race from the rules
>   listed above, except for aarakocra."  I found it in the monster
>   manual, but I don't understand how that allows you to build a PC.
>   That's why I'm curious about where all I can source my build from.

The player character race Aarakocra was  published in the Elelmental Evil Players Companion, [which was a free supplement available at the WoTC web site](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/EE_PlayersCompanion.pdf) for that season's play which was related to the Elemental Evil campaign.

Another supplement (for DM's) was published for [Hoard of the Dragon Queen](http://dnd.wizards.com/trpghoard-dragon-queen-supplement). Also at WoTC, home page.

What you will want to be on the lookout for at the WoTC home page is the .pdf supplement that they will most likely produce to accompany this season's play in Ravenloft.  You should probably check in every few days [to the downloads page to see what new arrivals are.](http://dnd.wizards.com/search/site/downloads?page=1)  If something for AL in the Ravenloft campaign is issued, like the Elemental Evil material, it may be there or [in the Adventurer League section of the WoTC web site.](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/events/adventurers-league-resources)