# When is Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide used?

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm kinda new to D&D.  I can't understand on which adventures I can use the guide. If you could explain when and on what adventures am I allowed to use the guide it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is this question about when it can be used in general, or are you asking about using it in sanctioned Adventurers League games?

Comment: I assume that's part of the question.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72453/when-will-the-sword-coast-adventurers-guide-content-be-allowed-on-adventurers?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

From the back of the SCAG:

> For use with the fifth edition Players Handbook, Monster Manual, and Dungeon Master's Guide, this book provides the setting, story and character options needed to participate in a D&D game anywhere along the Sword Coast of Faerûn.

**You do not need it necessarily**, but it may be useful for homebrew campaigns and if you want to use the provided character options.

The official adventure/campaign books provide enough content themselves, but if you want to expand the world the SCAG may help you with that as mentioned in *Strom King's Thunder*:

> The Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, while not required reading, has extensive information on the Sword Coast and the North that can help you flesh out the adventure's default setting.

Comment: It's also pretty much mandatory to run Storm King's Thunder, the sections on most cities basically just tell you to refer to the SCAG.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast not only for AL! The character options, in general, may be a reason to use the SCAG. Added it into the answer.

Comment: @r256 Added to note from SKT to the answer.